# 12V peristaltic pump flow control

Tags: circuit-analysis, schematics

I have 12V peristaltic pump and need to control its flow (lowering down more specifically)

Two options I came across:

1. POT in series
2. Voltage divider

Is there any **shortcomings in above schemes**?

What is best way to **reduce flow** without involving controller i.e using analog circuitry?

Comment: Reduced torque (easier to stall, poorer speed stability) is a shortcoming of both, which can be improved by using PWM control.

Comment: Can you please suggest any ref circuit? Thanks

Comment: Personally I wouldn't bother designing it for a one off job and just check eBay for a cheap PWM module that does the job at the required specs.

Comment: I want to make it without controller. Is there any option to do so?

Comment: Leave alone the electrical section to its original and do your mod on the fluid flow rate by installing a proportional valve.

Comment: The pot and voltage divider are both controllers anyway - just bad ones. A linear voltage regulator (LM317) with a pot is probably as simple as you can get (search "LM317" for example circuits) assuming your pump doesn't need more than 1 Amp.

Comment: Use smaller tubing (it is a peristaltic pump, so that's a VERY easy way to alter the volume delivered in a given time.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pot or voltage divider circuits don't work well because as the motor comes under load the current demand will increase and the voltage will drop. If you try it under load you will probably hear the motor speed rise and fall as the peristaltic rollers engage and disengage.

Here are two ideas:

1. Run the pump from a 6 V battery.
2. Drop the voltage using diodes.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fC5lw5.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Using diodes to drop voltage.*

Diodes have a much more constant voltage drop at varying currents. The circuit of Figure 1 shows a means of getting a range of near-constant voltages very easily. Allow 0.7 to 0.9 V voltage drop per diode. You haven't given us a motor rating so I've assumed it's small and that the voltage drop is 0.7 per diode.

Note that if you test with a multimeter the last two diodes on my schematic they would show 9.2 V as there is no current passing through them and, therefore, no voltage drop.